# Most efficient way to join tables after importing two datasets

Tags: mysql, csv, join

I created a table 'One' on mySQL where I import data from file111 (csv). It imports **dates** and **names**.

I created a table 'Two' where I import data from file222 (csv). It imports **old names** and **new names**.

Keep in mind that:

> One.names = Two.old_names

I want a final table will show the data from table 'One' but it will replace the **old names** with the **new names**.

Here is my code regarding the creation of the tables:

```
    -- Table creation : 'One'
    create table One(
    report_start date,
    name varchar(500)
    );

    -- Import of Data in the table 'One'
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/file111.csv'
    INTO TABLE One
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    ;

    -- Table creation with one column for the "old names" and one for the "new names" for "name" field.
    create table Two(
    old_name varchar(500),
    new_name varchar(500)
    );

    -- Import the OLD names and NEW names in the table 'Two'
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/file222.csv'
    INTO TABLE Two
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    ;
```

Now I have two options. One is **INSERT INTO** a third table after creating it. Exactly as shown below:

```
create table Three(
report_start date,
name varchar(500)
);

-- Our new table has all the data from 'One' except for the "name". The data will be imported in this column fields from the table "Two"
INSERT INTO Three (report_start, name)
SELECT report_start, Two.new_name 
FROM One
INNER JOIN Two ON Two.old_name = One.name
;
```

The other option is to UPDATE the first table and using JOIN :

```
update One 
join Two t on ( One.name = t.old_name )
set One.name=t.new_name;
```

They both work the same but which one is more efficient? I have started dealing with large amounts of data so I need get the most efficient and safe.

Comment: It makes no sense updating a table with the same value... Of course, this may be a oversimplified example, but... is that what you really need to do?

Comment: Are there any indexes on tables? And how many rows are we talking about, thousands or millions?

Comment: @KemalKefeli In this occasion it is thousands. No indexes on the tables.

Comment: Then, I think Insert operation should be faster than update. Because it means one join + one insert. The update one means, one join + search + one update.

Comment: @KemalKefeli Exactly. I have mentioned that below. I calculated the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most optimization related questions the answer is: well, it depends...

If the table containing the new names is significantly smaller than the 1st table, then an update will most likely be more efficient. Esspecially if you create indexes on the names and old_names columns.

If I were you, I would time both solutions (multiple times each) and use whichever works you the best.

Comment: INSERT INTO is way faster. If not in every occasion, for the specific tables I have, it is.

Answer (score 1):

You should write to a 3rd table, performance-wise its either the same or better, risk-wise its better. If you want to profile it you can:

```
SET profiling=1;
run query
SET profiling=0;
SHOW profiles;
```

I also suggest you INDEX the tables for the join if the data set is big.